# installing drivers on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Why is getting drivers installed on a new PC installation so difficult. I went to the Dell site and downloaded all the drivers. THen I went to device manager menu, and for each unknown device, I have to try every downloaded driver (around 25). I can't imagine everyone doing this... I mean first of all it does not search itself on the internet and secondly, we have to try each driver downloaded for each device. After doing all this, I still get driver not found for PCI device. I am tired. Can someone please tell me which driver I need to download for this? I don't want to try everything over again..

Answer (score 2):

It is only difficult on a clean installation, (I assume this is what you did).

There is a sequence to installing drivers, and if it is not followed, other subsequent drivers will not install properly.

This is the proper sequence for Dell PCs.

http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?journalid=4ED81717490911DC84EB0DC67E2C6D57&docid=3690A8CC21FAF290E040A68F5B281A12

Since you probably did not install them in the correct order, start over, reinstall XP clean and follow the order this time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install Dell drivers from device manager for each device. They are executables and can be executed just like any other install program. I'd also recommend naming the drivers once downloaded so you know what they correspond to (eg, chipset, Ethernet, video, sound).

I'd recommend installing the Ethernet adapters first so you can download the rest off of Dell's site from that same machine. Some vendors such as Lenovo also include a system update utility that you can use to update everything from the internet, provided you installed the Ethernet drivers already and have an active connection. Windows update will also pick up most drivers, but once again requires an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Driver Max](http://www.drivermax.com/).

You can import, export, and download the latest drivers for your device...I have used it to back up drivers and restore them later...